# How to deal with unexpected HTTP response code

Tags: rest, api-design

I'm working on an API, I have a `/POST` Method for registration ( */register* ) which returns a `200 status code` if `OK` or a `401 Unauthorized` in case of a `validation error`,

My question is what if my server didn't respond at all? May it return a certain `status code`?

What if there is a connection problem on my client side?
There will be some response code that I didn't specify on my `back end API`.

So how to deal with those response from the client App?

Comment: Your browser will probably throw a **408 - Request Time-out**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always should get a response code. If you don't expect your application to act in a way other than returning 200 or 401, simply present an elagant general error message in case the code is not one of those you expect:

"There might be a problem. Please, try again."

Comment: Interesting maybe i should go for that for now. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate more on **didn't respond at all**, it's because machine failure or something went wrong on your code?

In my opinion, when you're have access and the one who design the back-end API you should follow the principle of [HTTP status code](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), which something wrong on your code then it's should return **500 internal server error**. But if you're consuming third party API, generally they will follow the same HTTP status code, since it's the good practice.

Usually, I would design my client application show general error message for unpopular HTTP status code. Then for some specific HTTP status code such as **401 Unauthorized** or what you think the user need to know, I will give more detail information regarding what made the application error.

Comment: exactly when i say **'didn't respond at all'** i really mean **500 internal server error**. I'm the one building both front and back end. So i assume that i should check for **500 - internal server error + 408 - Request Time-out** along with those I've specified myself on the Back end?

Comment: Usually the general HTTP status code for something went wrong was 500, 400 and 404 which mostly I use when designed the API